# Axios get request returns error UNDEFINED

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I am trying to get the data from the certain API,I am getting an error:Undefined in the console.

```
const getApiAndEmit =async socket => {
    try 
    {
        
     
      await axios.get('https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByDistrict?district_id=571&date=25-05-2021').then((response) =>
      {
         this.resp=response.data;
      }) ;
     
      //socket.emit("FromAPI", this.resp);
      console.log(this.resp);
    } 
    catch (error) {
      
      console.error(`Error: ${error.code}`);
    }
  };
```

Json placeholder URL's and many other are returning the data in console.but this url returns error:Undefined.
Help please/

Comment: change `await axios.get(...)` to `const response = await axios.get(...)` and remove the `then()` method.

Comment: Still ,this doesn't work for this API! For other URL ,it works. But this url works fine in POSTMAN GET

Comment: can you share you output in postman

Comment: var axios = require('axios');
var data = '';

var config = {
  method: 'get',
  url: 'https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByDistrict?district_id=571&date=25-05-2021',
  headers: { },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you're expecting the error in your catch block to have a code, and that's not always what you'll see. In this case, axios is throwing a http error response, which you'll need to handle appropriately. [Axios has documentation on how to do this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#handling-errors)

You'll want to build out something more robust, but for now the following should work for this specific case, where you're only handling http error responses:

```
const getApiAndEmit = async (socket) => {
  try {
    let response = await axios.get(
      "https://cdn-api.co-vin.in/api/v2/appointment/sessions/public/findByDistrict?district_id=571&date=25-05-2021"
    );
    //socket.emit("FromAPI", this.resp);
    console.log(response);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
};
```